# mock type like "{[id: string]: Details}|null" in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mocking

Hello i got this type as in the title `{[id: string]: Details}|null` and Details interface is like this

```
export interface Details
{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  info: string;
}
```

how would i mock this? i mean i can easily mock the Details part like this

```
getDetails(): Details {

       const detailsOne =  (): Details => {
           return {
                id: 300,
                name: "Some Name",
                info: "Some Info"
          } as Details
      }

      return detailsOne();
}
```

But i am having troubles with understanding how return it within the [id: string] as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `{[id: string]: Details}|null` is the same as `Record<string, Details> | null` and has following structure representation :

```
type T = Record<string, Details> | null;
const a: T = {
  'anyString': {
      id: 300,
      name: "Some Name",
      info: "Some Info"
  }
}
// or
const b: T = null
```

Type `T` has two valid members - `key->value` map with `string` keys and `Details` objects as values, or `null`

Comment: Ah! thanks for explaining. made a lot more sense to me now.